# How does Firebase deal with changes made to the same node from different devices?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, let's assume that I have two devices; Device A and Device B.

Device A has booked 1 ticket for a movie and so has Device B.
When Device A, books 1 ticket, the 'Total Ticket Count' node decreases by 1 and the same thing happens when Device B also does this. But what if both these requests are made at the same instant? What happens in that case? Does Firebase queue up the requests and execute them based on timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in expecting that this situation may happen, and that the results are not well-defined.  Firebase Realtime Database gives you a way to deal with concurrent writes by providing [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) so that you can control writes to a given location that may be written by multiple clients simultaneously.  Proper use of [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) will avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helps!